# Как делается настройка скрипта в виде объекта?

Tags: javascript, объекты

Например у slick слайдера настройки передаются в виде объекта.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что это за тема javascript'a?

Comment: В чем вопрос то? Да, настройки передаются а виде объекта, потому что так удобнее, т.к. параметров может быть сколько угодно, и каждый параметр имеет свое имя и не нужно париться о том, в каком порядке передавать параметры

Comment: Это довольно распространенная практика, я в PHP передаю наборы параметров в виде ассоциативного массива

Answer (score 1):

Функция принимает один параметр *объект*, из которого берутся необходимые настройки.

Например:

```
function A(options){
    var option1 = options.option1 || "default";
}
```

Либо с деструктуризацией параметров:

```
function A({option1="default"}){
    ...
}
```

---

Данный подход применяется из-за отсутствия в яваскрипте именованных параметров.